# windows8 contest to take part

Tags: windows-runtime, setfocus

I'm trying to set focus on TextBox but Focus() method returns false

```
this.NameTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

However in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702161%28v=win.10%29.aspx) it is written:

> Focus(FocusState value)
>
> Return value: True if focus was set to the control, or focus was
>   already on the control. **False if the control is not focusable.**
>
> and
>
> You typically pass FocusState.Programmatic as the parameter to
>   indicate the control obtained focus through a deliberate call to the
>   Focus method. For example, if clicking an "Edit" button causes focus
>   to be set on a **TextBox**, use the Programmatic focus state.

So why does my command not work?

Comment: Your title looks like a mis-paste. Care to rewrite it?

Comment: A guess would be timing. The textbox is not in the visual tree or your doing this too early before the element is capable of taking focus. When are you calling Focus?